# How to Find Dimension of a Multiple Dimension Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I declared a 2-dimensional array like this:

```
char *array[][3] = {
    {"a", "b", "c"},
    {"d", "e", "f"},
    {"u", "v", "w"},
    {"x", "y", "z"}};
```

How do I find out the first dimension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### sizeof array / sizeof array[0]

Example:<sup>*</sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int array[4];

    printf("%zd\n", sizeof array / sizeof array[0]);
    printf("%zd\n", sizeof (int));
    printf("%ld\n", (long)(sizeof array / sizeof array[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>*You need the parens if the operand is a `type-name`, even though `sizeof` is an operator not a function. But every place where a `type-name` appears in the C grammar (declarators don't use that production) then parens are required around it. Because there isn't a separate production for a type-name-in-parens in the semi-formal grammars used for the various C specs, they specify the needed parens in the productions that define things like `sizeof`, `generic-associations`, and `cast-expressions`. But those parens are really there in order to be able to parse a type within the expression grammar. They are part of the syntax for something you might call "type expressions," but given the limited use of such things they don't actually have any such production or term.</sup>

Comment: If you use %d for C89, you should also use a cast to int.

Comment: True, or use %ld and cast to long. I've actually made that change a zillion times to squelch warnings on 64-bit systems. Should have mentioned it.

Comment: Parens around the operand of `sizeof` are not necessary with expressions (the parens in that case are simply more of the expression).  However, they are required if the operand to the sizeof operator is a type.

Comment: Also - even when using an expression as the operand to `sizeof`, I persnoally like parens since then I don't have to worry about remembering the precedence of the sizeof operator.  I have a hard time remembering more than "multiplication and division come before addition and subtraction".

Comment: Actually, the parens are part of what makes a type expression, not some requirement of `sizeof`. When people use `sizeof(int)` that's typically the one place where they do use `sizeof` as an operator, albeit without typically realizing it.

Comment: @DigitalRoss - (int) is not an expression.  The requirement of parens around a type operand to `sizeof` is because the standard says so: 6.5.3.4/2 of C99 (The sizeof operator), "The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
expression or the parenthesized name of a type."

Comment: I know, and I agree, it certainly does look like an arbitrary requirement of `sizeof` the way its written up, but the underlying reason is the same reason that casts have parens, the grammar is too ambiguous to easily parse a "type expression" without them.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you give:

```
sizeof(array) / sizeof(char*) / 3
```

a shot?

This is assuming you know the data type (char*) and other dimension (3).

You divide the size of the structure by the size of each element to get the total number of elements, then divide it by the first dimension, giving you the second.

*Aside:* my original answer used `'sizeof("a")'` which was, of course, wrong, since it was the size of the array (2, being 'a' and '\0'), not the pointer (4 on my hideously outdated 32-bit machine). But I love the way I got two upvotes for that wrong answer - don't you bods actually check the answers here before voting? :-)

Comment: Not a very elegant solution - compared with DigitalRoss's solution.  You have to know quite a bit about the type to write that.  And yes, people do up-vote without always checking the answer - or spotting the problem with the answer.